# htaccess rewrite 301 redirect rule without www

Tags: .htaccess

I have a client who has a rewrite rule on their website that uses 404 and SSL with https:  but it always rewrites to 'www.mywebsite.com' .  They want it without the www.  whenever I try to modify the rule the code breaks with 'too many redirects'

Here's the old .htaccess rule

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} .
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

ErrorDocument 404 http://www.mywebsite.com
```

I've tried to remove the 'www' above but when I do that, you get an error - endless redirects.

The goal is a simple rewrite rule that allows all redirects and 404 errors to go to https://mywebsite.com  with a 301

Answer (score 0):

My engineer found a solution so I'm posting it here.

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://mywebsite.com/$1 [R,L]
ErrorDocument 404 http://mywebsite.com
```

Comment: Does this really work? This should cause endless redirects too. If someone directly visits `https://mywebsite.com/`, then this will keep redirecting and end in an infinite loop I presume.

Comment: Why there is `http` in `ErrorDocument` instead of `https` ?

Answer (score 0):

Let me explain you previous rules :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} .
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
ErrorDocument 404 http://www.mywebsite.com
```

This line `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} .` is matching any request start with any character except newline.

This line `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]` is matching any request not start with `www`.

This line `RewriteRule ^ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]` is to force what satisy the previous conditions , which is only request without `www`, and fore it into `https` + `wwww` and that why you faced that problem .

The new rules :

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://mywebsite.com/$1 [R,L]
ErrorDocument 404 http://mywebsite.com
```

these in general will match `http` requests by this `RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80`  and force them into `https` without `www`.

But that will not force `https://www` into `https://` so change them to :

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://mywebsite.com/$1 [R,L]
ErrorDocument 404 http://mywebsite.com
```

If this code is Ok , change `[R,L]` to `[R=301,L]` to be permenant redirection because `R` flag alone means `302` which is temporary .